# cookie_str = match.group(1).AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python

I am working on Stock predicting project.I want to download historical data from yahoo finance and save them in CSV format.

Since I am beginner in Python I am unable to correct the error.

My code is as follows:

```
    import re
import urllib2
import calendar
import datetime
import getopt
import sys
import time

crumble_link = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{0}/history?p={0}'
crumble_regex = r'CrumbStore":{"crumb":"(.*?)"}'
cookie_regex = r'Set-Cookie: (.*?); '
quote_link = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{}?period1={}&period2={}&interval=1d&events=history&crumb={}'


def get_crumble_and_cookie(symbol):
    link = crumble_link.format(symbol)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(link)
    match = re.search(cookie_regex, str(response.info()))
    cookie_str = match.group(1)
    text = response.read()
    match = re.search(crumble_regex, text)
    crumble_str = match.group(1)
    return crumble_str, cookie_str


def download_quote(symbol, date_from, date_to):
    time_stamp_from = calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime.strptime(date_from, "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple())
    time_stamp_to = calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime.strptime(date_to, "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple())

    attempts = 0
    while attempts < 5:
        crumble_str, cookie_str = get_crumble_and_cookie(symbol)
        link = quote_link.format(symbol, time_stamp_from, time_stamp_to, crumble_str)
        #print link
        r = urllib2.Request(link, headers={'Cookie': cookie_str})

        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(r)
            text = response.read()
            print "{} downloaded".format(symbol)
            return text
        except urllib2.URLError:
            print "{} failed at attempt # {}".format(symbol, attempts)
            attempts += 1
            time.sleep(2*attempts)
    return ""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print get_crumble_and_cookie('KO')
    from_arg = "from"
    to_arg = "to"
    symbol_arg = "symbol"
    output_arg = "o"
    opt_list = (from_arg+"=", to_arg+"=", symbol_arg+"=")
    try:
        options, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],output_arg+":",opt_list)
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        print err

    for opt, value in options:
        if opt[2:] == from_arg:
            from_val = value
        elif opt[2:] == to_arg:
            to_val = value
        elif opt[2:] == symbol_arg:
            symbol_val = value
        elif opt[1:] == output_arg:
            output_val = value

    print "downloading {}".format(symbol_val)
    text = download_quote(symbol_val, from_val, to_val)

    with open(output_val, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(text)
    print "{} written to {}".format(symbol_val, output_val)
```

And the Error message that I am getting is :

```
File "C:/Users/Murali/PycharmProjects/generate/venv/tcl/generate2.py", line 
49, in <module>
print get_crumble_and_cookie('KO')
File "C:/Users/Murali/PycharmProjects/generate/venv/tcl/generate2.py", line 
19, in get_crumble_and_cookie
cookie_str = match.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

So how can we resolve this problem that has popped up?

Comment: The error message indicates that `match = re.search(crumble_regex, text)` was unsuccessful in finding the regex pattern. You should check that `match` is not `None` before moving on in your code and make sure that `text` is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Look at these two commands:

```
match = re.search(cookie_regex, str(response.info()))
cookie_str = match.group(1)
```

The first one takes the string `response.info()` does a regular expression search to match `cookie_regex`.  Then `match.group(1)` is supposed to take the match from it.  The problem however is that if you do a `print match` in between these commands, you'll see that the `re.search()` returned nothing.  This means match.group() has nothing to "group", which is why it errors out.

If you take a closer look at `response.info()` (you could just add a `print response.info()` command in your script to see it), you'll see that there's a line in  response code that starts with "set-cookie:", the code after which you're trying to capture.  However, you have your `cookie_regex` string set to look for a line with "**S**et-**C**ookie:".  Note the capital letters. When I change that string to all lower-case, the error goes away:

```
cookie_regex = r'set-cookie: (.*?); '
```

I did run into another error after that, where `print "downloading {}".format(symbol_val)` stops because `symbol_val` hasn't been defined.  It seems that this variable is only declared and assigned when `opt[2:] == symbol_arg:`.  So you may want to rewrite that part to cover all cases.